# Selenium Webdriver using java window handling

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am getting two names following with a comma sign,
While getting names of windows using windows handle.

But each time I run the script I notice that both the names are changed (every time I run I get new name of the windows).
I want to use y ( from x, y) ... And I  print them in my console.
Can you please tell me how can I read and use my printed output. 
For eg:
Output is:
Windows names are: X, Y
Now I want to use Y and then switch to the other window.
Note: This windows appears upon click of a button,then I get the names of both windows.
Kindly share some knowledge.

Comment: Store the `driver.getWindowHandle()` in a `String` variable and then `split` the string to get the `Y` that you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Try the Below code,

```
 public class TestNaukri {

    @Test
    public void TestPopUp() throws InterruptedException{
    // Open browser
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

    // Maximize browser
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Load app
    driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");

    // It will return the parent window name as a String
    String parent=driver.getWindowHandle();

    // This will return the number of windows opened by Webdriver and will return Set of St//rings
    Set<String>s1=driver.getWindowHandles();

    // Now we will iterate using Iterator
    Iterator<String> I1= s1.iterator();

    while(I1.hasNext())
    {

       String child_window=I1.next();

    // Here we will compare if parent window is not equal to child window then we            will close

    if(!parent.equals(child_window))
    {
    driver.switchTo().window(child_window);

    System.out.println(driver.switchTo().window(child_window).getTitle());

    driver.close();
    }

    }
    // once all pop up closed now switch to parent window
    driver.switchTo().window(parent);

    }
    }
```